# VBA Access 2007 - ODBC cannot lock all records

Tags: vba, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2007

I'm working on a heavy project which consists in migrating Microsoft Access local tables to Microsoft SQL Server, and I'm having troubles with a specific one.

I'm using the ODBC driver to MS SQL Server to link to my table `IMMATRICULATION`. Its column name `IMMAT` is a primary key. In my VBA code, I'm running this:

```
Dim mydb As Database
Dim myrs As Recordset
Dim req As String
Set mydb = CurrentDb()

DoCmd.Hourglass True

req = "SELECT * FROM IMMATRICULATION WHERE IMMAT ='" & Me.Liste_CANum & "'"
Set myrs = mydb.OpenRecordset(req, dbOpenDynaset, dbDenyWrite)

If myrs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    IMMAT = myrs![IMMAT]
    MARQUE = myrs![MARQUE]
    MODELE = myrs![MODELE]
    PRIX = myrs![PRIX]
    DATE = myrs![DATE]
    AMO_DUREE = myrs![AMO_DUREE]
    AMO_MONTANT = myrs![AMO_MONTANT]
    AMO_DEBUT = myrs![AMO_DEBUT]
    AMO_FIN = myrs![AMO_FIN]
    ASS_MONTANT = myrs![ASS_MONTANT]
    SOM = myrs![SOMMEIL]
Else
    myrs.AddNew
    myrs![IMMAT] = Me.Liste_CANum
    myrs.Update
    IMMAT = Me.Liste_CANum
    MARQUE = ""
    MODELE = ""
    PRIX = ""
    DATE = ""
    AMO_DUREE = ""
    AMO_MONTANT = ""
    AMO_DEBUT = ""
    AMO_FIN = ""
    ASS_MONTANT = ""
    SOM = "Non"
End If
myrs.Close
mydb.Close
DoCmd.Hourglass False
```

but this line of code doesn't work:

```
Set myrs = mydb.OpenRecordset(req, dbOpenDynaset, dbDenyWrite)
```

And the following error message pops-up:

```
ODBC -- cannot lock all records
```

Do you have any ideas of how to solve my problem? I tried to remove the `dbDenyWrite` but the problem isn't solved.

Thanks

Comment: *"I tried to remove the dbDenyWrite but the problem isn't solved."* - what does that mean exactly? The same error is shown? Or another problem arises? -- You don't edit an existing record, so I don't see why you would need `dbDenyWrite` at all.

Comment: Just use mydb.openrecordset(req) does it still give you error?

Comment: try adding the `dbSeeChanges` switch, see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx)